# how to change the format of solr last index

Tags: mongodb, solr

I want to perform delta import fro that I need to compare my update date with Solr's last_index_time. so I have a problem to compare to two different format my format of update date is 2019-01-29T05:06:02.192Z But Solr last_index_Time format is 2019-01-30 10:07:58, So, I want to change my solr last_index_time format in my object Date format. Can anyone help me for that?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, **propertyWriter** is used to change `last_index_time` format in SOLR *(SOLR-2658)*

```
<propertyWriter dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" type="SimplePropertiesWriter" filename="dataimport.properties" locale="en_US"/>
```

Note: Additionally, this adds a `<propertyWriter />` element to DIH's data-config.xml file, allowing the user to specify the location, filename and Locale for the "data-config.properties" file.

Comment: Added attribute `filename="dataimport.properties"` as per you specified in the comment. This might help.